# Dividing space equally between unknown number of components in Swing?

Tags: java, swing, layout

I have a Java Swing application that has a bar of `JButton`s. The number of them is not known beforehand. I'd like to size the buttons equally to fit in the frame. Also, I need to be able to add new buttons and have them resized automatically.

For example in Android you can use the layout weight attribute to do this. Now, is there any `Layout` etc. in Swing that can do it for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GridLayout` arranges all its components with equal size by default

Comment: Yes, but it requires the coder to set the amount of rows and columns. I have an unknown number of components.

Comment: Does it matter whether, for example, 12 buttons are arranged in one, two, three, four, six or 12 rows?

Comment: I would like them all in one row.

Comment: Then use a `new GridLayout(1,0)` - this specifies 1 row, but an arbitrary number of columns. The actual number of columns is computed automatically as the components are added.

Comment: Derp, just noticed `new GridLayout()` does that too.